# Telegraf x509 input to monitor Kafka SSL endpoint

Tags: apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, monitoring, x509, telegraf

I wondered how I can monitor Kafka SSL endpoint with x509 telegraf input as it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here is my input configuration:

```
#
# INPUTS:
#
[[inputs.x509_cert]]
sources = ["https://mykafka.example.com:9093"]
```

And here is what I get in telegraf logs:

```
mykafka.example.com 06:46:41 ~ # systemctl status telegraf -l
● telegraf.service - The plugin-driven server agent for reporting metrics into InfluxDB
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/telegraf.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-06-12 15:24:13 UTC; 6 days ago
     Docs: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf
 Main PID: 29548 (telegraf)
    Tasks: 10
   Memory: 78.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/telegraf.service
           └─29548 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d

Jun 19 06:37:45 mykafka.example.com telegraf[29548]: 2020-06-19T06:37:45Z E! [inputs.x509_cert] Error in plugin: cannot get SSL cert 'https://mykafka.example.com:9093': local error: tls: unexpected message
Jun 19 06:38:45 mykafka.example.com telegraf[29548]: 2020-06-19T06:38:45Z E! [inputs.x509_cert] Error in plugin: cannot get SSL cert 'https://mykafka.example.com:9093': local error: tls: unexpected message
Jun 19 06:39:45 mykafka.example.com telegraf[29548]: 2020-06-19T06:39:45Z E! [inputs.x509_cert] Error in plugin: cannot get SSL cert 'https://mykafka.example.com:9093': local error: tls: unexpected message
```

I also tried with `tcp://mykafka.example.com:9093` (instead of https) with the exact same result.

And openssl is returning me the served certficate without any issue, if I do: `openssl s_client -connect mykafka.example.com:9093` I have the information I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance for your help, should it be with telegraf x509 input or with any other solution that can come around.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the plugin a try to check the `x509_cert` plugin to connect to the Kafka Broker's SSL port directly and it works fine for me. Here is my config:

```
[[inputs.x509_cert]]
  sources = [ "tcp://kafkabr3test.example.com:9093" ]
  tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/MMW-CA-SHA256.cer.crt"
```

I've tested it with version `1.25` of telegraf.